# Use fields from user's profile as title of view?

Tags: views, entities, users

I have a view that displays, let's say, videos that each user has added. This view is shown in their profile. I'd like to use fields from their profile as the title of the view. Specifically, fields containing their first and last name. So for instance, I'd like the title to be "Ashton Kutcher's Videos."

I know that you can use arguments to alter the title of a view, but I can't seem to find a way to use the content of fields.

Additionally, because of a silly decision when building the site, I did not require users to enter their names. Therefore, sometimes I will need to display their username instead of their first and last names, conditionally.

Any suggestions?

Comment: For the actual username problems you mention, There's a Module for That: http://drupal.org/project/realname

Comment: So Realname actually replaces the username anywhere that it would appear? That's cool. I didn't realize that it functioned that way. I thought that it just combined other specified name fields into a single one that can be used wherever any other field could be used. I didn't see much use for it.

Comment: Yep! And it allows a lot of customization, too, as does Drupal's hook_username_alter() - http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_username_alter/7